# How to group data based on max value of a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table by the name of purchase_details which has the following data:

| purchase_id | product_id | purchase_price | sale_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 15000 | 16000 |
| 4 | 1 | 13000 | 14000 |
| 3 | 4 | 500 | 700 |
| 2 | 4 | 400 | 500 |

I want to select data based on max purchase_id for every product like the following:

| purchase_id | product_id | purchase_price | sale_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 13000 | 14000 |
| 3 | 4 | 500 | 700 |

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use analytic function (such as `row_number` or `rank`) to "sort" data; then extract rows that rank as the highest:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with purchase_Details (purchase_id, product_id, purchase_price, sale_price) as
  2    (select 3, 1, 15000, 16000 from dual union all
  3     select 4, 1, 13000, 14000 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 4,   500,   700 from dual union all
  5     select 2, 4,   400,   500 from dual
  6    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  7  temp as
  8    (select p.*,
  9       row_number() over (partition by product_id order by purchase_id desc) rn
 10     from purchase_details p
 11    )
 12  select purchase_id, product_id, purchase_price, sale_price
 13  from temp
 14  where rn = 1;

PURCHASE_ID PRODUCT_ID PURCHASE_PRICE SALE_PRICE
----------- ---------- -------------- ----------
          4          1          13000      14000
          3          4            500        700

SQL>
```

Comment: Note that ORACLE supports IN() on tuples - not all RDBMS do - so 
SELECT * FROM purchase_Details 
WHERE (product_id, purchase_id) IN (
  SELECT product_id, MAX(purchase_id) FROM purchase_Details GROUP BY product_id
)
;
will also work and may take advantage of a compound index.